# Update Text after Button press - in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, button, widget

I'm currently working on a Random Simpson Episode generator.

I want the user to get a random season and a random episode after pressing one button.
At the moment "onpressed" launches a function called "randomEpisode". In there the season and episode is randomly picked.

Now I don't know how to update the Text that shows the season and episode.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  Random random = new Random();
  int season = 0;
  int episode = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/Loading.jpg'),
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                  Text(
                    'Season: $season ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 50.0,
                      letterSpacing: 2.0,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  Text(
                    'Episode:  $episode',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 50.0,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () => randomEpisode(),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    elevation: 5,
                    child: const Text('Random',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        )),
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  randomEpisode() {
    List<int> numberepisodes = [
      13,
      22,
      24,
      22,
      22,
      25,
      25,
      25,
      25,
      23,
      22,
      21,
      22,
      22,
      22,
      21,
      22,
      22,
      20,
      21,
      23,
      22,
      22,
      22,
      22,
      22,
      22,
      22,
      21,
      23,
      22,
    ];

    Random random = new Random();
    int season;
    int episode;
    int maxseason;
    int maxepisode;
    //_changeEpisode();
    print('numberepisodes: $numberepisodes');
    maxseason = numberepisodes.length;
    print('maxseason $maxseason');
    season =
        1 + random.nextInt(numberepisodes.length - 1);

    print('season $season');
    maxepisode = numberepisodes[season - 1];
    print('maxepisodes $maxepisode');

    episode =
        1 + random.nextInt(numberepisodes[season - 1] - 1);
    print('Season: $season , Episode:  $episode');

  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove below local variables from `randomEpisode()` method

```
int season;
int episode;
```

And call the below method at the end of `randomEpisode()` method.

setState(() {});